# Is it possible to restore mongodb database after removing and restarting mongo docker container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, restore, repair

I have a mongodb container with the db set to my local data folder using `volume: ./data :/data/db.`
After restarts it was working OK but after I removed the container with `docker rm mongo` and restarted, it stopped showing my database.

There are WiredTiger files in my local folder, but mongo --restore doesn't help.

Is it possible to recover the db somehow?

Comment: with what command did you restart the container after removing it?

Comment: I've tried with mongod --dbpath /data --repair --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log

Comment: I noticed that with this command mongo exists with code 1, when I launch withouth --fork it exits with code 0 then the container restarts again and again.

Comment: hi, do you have any luck restoring the data? I kind of having the same issue

Comment: @encryptoferia did you solve it, i am in the same boat :)

Comment: @caniaskyouaquestion sadly, no